# Under what circumstances would this happen in rails (db)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Utterly confused at this mess:

```
rake db:drop
>
rake db:create
> my_database already exists
rake db:migrate
> unknown database my_database
```

Appreciate any insight.

Comment: your migration file might not be set up appropriately.

Comment: your test database could be named "my_database"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because first time when u do rake db:create it creates two databases one is development and other is test. then when u do rake db:drop it drops the database, but it only drops the development database not the test database. so try removing the test database explicitly and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create RAILS_ENV=development
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

if getting same error then open mysql terminal and create database manually :

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name;
```

then run

```
rake db:migrate
```